# How do I unit test a HOC having an async componentDidMount using jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs, higher-order-components

This is my react HOC:

```
import React from "react"
import { getData } from 'services/DataService'

export function withData(WrappedComponent, count) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    state = { 
      data: [] 
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ 
        data: await getData(count) 
      })
    }

    render() {
      const { data } = this.state
      return data.length > 0 && <WrappedComponent data={data} />
    }
  }
}
```

I want to write a unit test to prove that if `getData(count)` returns some data, the `WrappedComponent` is correctly rendered OR at least `state.data.length` is greater than zero.

I mocked the `getData` like this in my test with a valid `mockResponse`:

```
  jest.mock("services/DataService", () => ({
    getData: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockResponse))
  }))
```

But I am stuck at this point. Community has some answers about testing components having an async componentDidMount, but none of them are related with HOCs. I tried things like this:

```
const WithReleaseNotesComponent = withReleaseNotes(mockedComponent)
```

and then trying to instantiate or mount `WithReleaseNotesComponent`, but I've never seen they have right state/props that I can test against. state/props are always empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my mock. I don't know why, but `jest.mock()` didn't work as expected. I replaced it with a `jest.spyOn()` and then called `shallow` with `await`. Everything worked out perfectly. There wasn't even any need to flush promises.

`withDataHOC.spec.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { withData } from 'components/higher-order-components/WithDataHOC'
import * as dataService from 'services/DataService'

describe("WithDataHOC", () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })

  const mockedComponent = jest.fn()

  it("doesn't render anything if there are no data", async() => {    
    jest.spyOn(dataService, "getData").mockImplementation( () => Promise.resolve()) 
    const WithDataComponent = withData(mockedComponent)
    const wrapper = shallow(<WithDataComponent />)
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
  const mockResponse = JSON.parse(require('services/__mocks__/DataResponse').dataResponseCache)

  it("renders correctly if there are data", async() => {     
    jest.spyOn(dataService, "getData").mockImplementation( () => Promise.resolve(mockResponse)) 
      const WithDataComponent = withData(mockedComponent)
      const wrapper = await shallow(<WithDataComponent />)            
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()        
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use the `enzyme` library to test your components. In order to ensure that the asynchronous task execution of the `componentDidMount` life cycle method using `async/await` syntax is completed, we need to flush the promise queue.

For more info about how does flush promise queue doing, see [macrotasks-and-microtasks](https://javascript.info/event-loop#macrotasks-and-microtasks)

> All microtasks are completed before any other event handling or rendering or any other macrotask takes place.

Which means the `async/await` and promise are microtasks that they will be completed before macrotask created by `setTimeout`.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { getData } from './services/DataService';

export function withData(WrappedComponent, count) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    state = {
      data: [],
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        data: await getData(count),
      });
    }

    render() {
      const { data } = this.state;
      return data.length > 0 && <WrappedComponent data={data} />;
    }
  };
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withData } from './';
import { getData } from './services/DataService';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('./services/DataService');

const mockedGetData = mocked(getData);

class MockedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>mocked component</div>;
  }
}

function flushPromises() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
}

describe('66260393', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should render wrapped component', async () => {
    mockedGetData.mockResolvedValueOnce('fake data');
    const WithDataComponent = withData(MockedComponent, 1);
    const wrapper = shallow(<WithDataComponent></WithDataComponent>);
    expect(wrapper.state('data')).toEqual([]);
    await flushPromises();
    expect(wrapper.state('data')).toEqual('fake data');
    expect(wrapper.find(MockedComponent)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find(MockedComponent).prop('data')).toEqual('fake data');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66260393/index.test.tsx
  66260393
    ✓ should render wrapped component (23 ms)

-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File               | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files          |      90 |      100 |      80 |      90 |                   
 66260393          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  index.tsx        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 66260393/services |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 |                   
  DataService.ts   |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2                 
-------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.198 s
```

Comment: I don't use that 'ts-jest/utils' library so couldn't exactly test your solution, but yes, the problem was my mock.

Comment: @schlingel Just remove this line, the others are same